# What was the police officer's idea?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

Two police officers suspected a man of kidnapping. Without sufficient evidence they couldn't search his car or his home. They also couldn't interrogate him. One officer had an idea which later led to the man's arrest. What was the police officer's idea?

Comment: Isn't this a bit broad?

Comment: The real answer: The policeman asked the guy if he did it and the kidnapper felt guilty and said yes.

Answer (score 1):

Did he

> Ask the child, "Did that man kidnap you?" :)

Answer (score 1):

> We aren't told he was arrested **for kidnapping**

So:

> Maybe they followed him and caught him doing something else illegal (i.e. speeding, jaywalking, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

> They arranged for a news report saying the victim had escaped. The man then went to the place he was holding the victim to see if the victim was still there, and the police followed him.